# Duplicated downloads - Cordova/Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

**EDITED**:
I have a function to download files and a event to listen clicks that start this download

Event:

```
$$('button').on('click', function() {                                   
    var media = $$(this).attr('data-url');              
    Download(media);
    }
});
```

"Download" is a function that delay to be completed... While it runs, if i click in other button to get its value, the "media" var will get the value of the first button - That is being proccessed in "Download" function

How i do fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Have to show the problem code for that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it this way:

My page has several buttons and i think that it was causing conflicts. So, i create a "dynamic class" with a part of link and link a event to them, instead of button.

```
    //My file is in this link. The absolute link to my jpg file will be catched in JSON inside here...
    var link = 'https://www.myserver1.com/f/wPAU322jT36/'; 
    var id_link_1 = link.substring(28,100); //-> wPAU322jT36/
    var id_link = id_link_1.replace('/',''); //-> wPAU322jT36
```

So, i put it as a class in html:

```
   //data-url is my .jpg file catched in JSON in link above
    var html = '<button data-url="https://www.myserver1.com/myfie.jpg" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block '+id_link+'"';
```

So, i call it inside a event

```
$$('.'+id_link+'').on('click', function() {                                   
    var media = $$(this).attr('data-url');              
    Download(media);
    }
});
```

So I got unique classes to be called. Now, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you like this before. Then I solved them.

Try to put `.off('click')` before `.on('click')`, it will solved your problem.

So it's will be look like :

```
$$('button').off('click').on('click', function() {                                   
  var media = $$(this).attr('data-url');              
  Download(media);
});
```

**OR**

Add the `off('click')` inside your function at the end.

```
$$('button').on('click', function() {                                   
  var media = $$(this).attr('data-url');              
  Download(media);
  $$(this).off('click');
});
```

Comment: Your solution is good... But no works for me... I solve other way... see above :)